Unit in $(\mathbb{Z}/5)[x]/\langle x^4-x^2\rangle$
I came across the question:

Determine if the element $x^3 + 2 + \langle x^4 − x^2\rangle\in (\mathbb{Z}/5[x])/\langle x^4 − x^2\rangle$ is a unit.

Notation: $\langle  x^4 − x^2\rangle$ is the ideal generated by $ x^4 − x^2$.
My guess is that it is a unit, but I can't figure out how to calculate the multiplicative inverse. I know that for it to be a unit, there has to be a polynomial $p(x)\in (\mathbb{Z}/5)[x]$ such that
\begin{equation}
p(x)(x^3 +2)-1\in \langle x^4-x^2\rangle . 
\end{equation}
In other words, there has to be polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that
\begin{equation}
p(x)(x^3 +2)= q(x)(x^4-x^2)+1. 
\end{equation}
Which implies $p(x)$ has to have a constant term that is equal to $3$. But I don't know how to proceed from this point.
In an attempt to use another approach, I used the division algorithm which lead me to
\begin{equation}
(x^2+3x+1)(x^4-x^2)= (x^3+3x)(x^3+2). 
\end{equation}
And this made me rethink, I am actually not sure if $x^3 + 2 + \langle x^4 − x^2\rangle$ is a unit now.
Any help is gladly appreciated.

Related. You can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the inverse. Examples of that (there are many on this site) typically have an irreducible polynomial in place of $x^4-x^2=x^2(x-1)(x+1)$, but the algorithm works the same as long as the element to be inverted is represented by a coprime polynomial.

By here in the linked dupe: $,f,$ is a unit in $,\Bbb F_5[x]/(g)\iff \gcd(f,g)=1,$ in $,\Bbb F_5[x]\ \ $

Note that the coprimality $,\gcd(f,g)=1,$ can be quickly verified w/o the Euclidean algorithm since here $f$ is coprime to $,x,,x\pm1,$ by $,f(0),f(\pm1)\neq 0$ in $\Bbb Z_5,,$ hence $f$ is coprime to their product $, g = x^2(x-1)(x+1),,$ i.e. units (invertibles) in the quotient are closed under product. $\ \ $

In $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z$, $a$ is a unit if and only if $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime.
Similarly, when $K$ is a field and $f(x) \in K[x]$, $f(x)$ is a unit in $K[x]/(g(x))$ if and only if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime.
You ask abou $K = \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, $f(x) = x^3+2$, and $g(x) = x^4-x^2 = x^2(x-1)(x+1)$. Do you see any nonconstant common factors between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)[x]$?

No, there are no common factors. So it is a unit! But now I have two questions: 1) How could one go about proving the first assertion (with $f$ and $g$ relatively prime). 2) is it still possible to find an inverse?

If you know how to prove in $\mathbf Z$ that $a \bmod m$ is invertible if and only if $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then adapt that argument to $K[x]$. If you do not know how to prove the result in $\mathbf Z$, then learn that first. Similarly, to invert $f(x) \bmod g(x)$, take a method that computes the inverse of $a \bmod m$ and adapt that to the polynomial setting. In short, make sure you can treat the more basic case of $\mathbf Z$ and then adjust the method there to handle polynomials.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Just like to compute modular inverses, you can do an extended GCD algorithm to get $af + bg = \gcd(f, g)$ and if that gcd is $1$ (or another unit) then $bg \equiv 1 \pmod f$.
Here we have (quotients and remainders, using long division):
\begin{align}
x^4 + 4x^2 &= x(x^3 + 2) + (4x^2 + 3x) \tag1 \\
x^3 + 2 &= (4x + 2)(4x^2 + 3x) + 4x + 2 \tag2 \\
4x^2 + 3x &= (x + 4)(4x + 2) + 2 \tag3
\end{align}
So we get $2$ (a unit) as our gcd. Then we can solve for $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ by solving each of these quotient/remainder equations for the remainder and substituting each into the next.
For example, equation (1) says that
$$f = xg + (4x^2 + 3x) \longrightarrow4x^2 +3x = f + 4xg$$
and then you can substitute that into (2):
$$g = (4x + 2)(4x^2 + 3x) + 4x + 2$$
to get $4x + 2 = (\cdots) f + (\cdots) g$. And then substitute that into (3).
I also recommend at some point starting to use a computer algebra system to do these calculations. E.g. in SageMath it's
R.<x> = GF(5)[]
f = x^4 - x^2
g = x^3 + 2
xgcd(f, g)

ee https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html for info about the RingName.<variables> = BaseRing[] notation.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

fyi: the extended Euclidean algorithm is simpler and less error prone if not done backwards, e.g. see here in the lined dupe.
